# Return an open socket connection/leave a socket connection open C++

Tags: c++, sockets, oop, inheritance, return

So i am new to c++ socket programming and i'm writing a library for a certain protocol.

I have a class in which has a function called Quick_Connect(hostname, port), and i've ran into trouble figuring out how i would go about doing something like the following when the library is in use:

```
ClassName.Quick_Connect();
ClassName.SomeOtherMethod();
```

where some other method sends a protocol message to the open socket that is created with Quick_Connect().

Sorry if this is a stupid question, i'm pretty new to c++ and low level networking. I don't know if this is possible or if it will require a revamp of the structure of the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use member variable of you class. Just define socket member in class and in `Quick_Connect` set this variable.

Then latter you can use it from other method. It will be wrapped inside you object.

```
class Protocol
{
public:
    Quick_Connect()
    {
        m_Socket = CreateSocket();
    };

    SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        if (m_Socket)
        {
            // use your m_Socket for sending data.    
        }
    };

private:
    Socket m_Socket;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! :) , this works. Don't know how i didn't think of it.